# Formula to convert Julian to Calendar date

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have created a calculated column with which i want to convert julian date (from another column) to calendar

Does anyone know a formula to do that? I've searched the web but I can only find from calendar to julian (for SharePoint)

Answer (score 0):

A Julian date refers to a date format that is a combination of the current year and the number of days since the beginning of the year.

For example, January 1, 2007, is represented as 2007001 and December 31, 2007, is represented as 2007365. This format is not based on the Julian calendar. ([Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)))

I was able to create a formula to convert Julian date into normal date.

```
=TEXT(DATE(LEFT([JulianDate],4),01,01),"YYYY-MM-DD") + (RIGHT([JulianDate],3) - 1)
```

**Column Details**

- JulianDate = Column type : single line text
- CalenderDate = Column type : calculated column , Data type returned : Date and Time , Date and time format: Date Only

And apply the above formuale to **CalenderDate** it will convert the values.

**Examples**

- 1998098 will become 4/8/1998
- 1999234 will become 8/22/1999
- 2022308 will become 11/4/2022

Please make appropriate modifications to the formula to exactly match your requirement.